# run multiple js files without starting and stopping server every time

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a grunt configuration running a test suite that, for now, i can't change how it's structured.

At some point, i have an array of file paths, and do something like:

```
files.forEach(function(testFile){
   grunt.task.run( 'shell:phantomjs:' +  testFile );
});
```

and

```
grunt.initConfig({
   phantomjs: {
      command: function(testFile){
          return 'node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs ' + testFile;
      }
   }
});
```

The problem with this approach is SPEED.
As i'm running phantomjs for each file, the setup and takedown of the server on each run makes my tests take longer than 4 minutes to run.

I am looking for a way of calling phantomjs with a blob path like `tests/**/*.js`, or even an array of the filenames, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problem that you need to deal with.

### Passing test files

`tests/**/*.js` is a glob wildcard syntax for which there is a [node.js module](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/). The problem is that PhantomJS has a different runtime than node.js and the fs module has vastly different functions. Because of this, you cannot just require node-glob. You would have to port [it](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/glob.js) to PhantomJS. There is a [feature-request](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10810) to include this right in PhantomJS.

If you have many test files and you want to pass them separately to the main PhantomJS script, you may run into a problem with the length of the command line call. Depending on the shell/OS the buffer may hold only a limited amount of characters for the command and test files.

It would be the easiest to curate all test files in a separate file as a list and just pass this file into the main PhantomJS script. You could also just have the list of files in the main script.

### Running multiple scripts in series

Regardless, what you do, you will need to clear cookies and localStorage between tests. I'm not sure if cache can be cleared.

#### 1. adjusted

You may have to adjust your test scripts. When you call `phantom.exit()`, the whole process terminates. It cannot be prevented by overwriting `exit` like this

```
phantom.exit = function(){};
```

because it is a native property. You would need to change your scripts in something like a module:

```
module.exports = function(done){
    // your script ...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // some more of your script
        // add clean up and queue next script...
        page.close(); // clean up memory consumption; might still be not enough
        done(); // call instead of "phantom.exit();"
    }, 1000);
};
```

The main script would look like this:

```
var testfiles = ["..."];
var async = require("async"); // install async through npm
testfiles = testfiles.map(function(file){
    return require(file);
});
async.series(testfiles, function(err){
    console.log("ERROR", err);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

If you only use one `page` instance throughout you can try to create it in the main file and pass it to every test file separately. That will likely fix your memory consumption, if this is a problem.

#### 2. without change

There is also the possibility that you don't need to change your test files. You can read your test files into strings using `fs.read`. You can change some things using string operations/regex to exchange `phantom.exit();` for `done();` and adding a line to close the page.

When you're done, you can just `eval` the string (asynchronously). Using `eval` is likely not a security problem since it's likely that you have written the test scripts.